# Am I using correct SSL ciphers - need to find a balance between security and speed

Tags: linux, nginx, ssl

I'm using the following SSL configuration on my nginx server:

```
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 30m;
ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.pem;
ssl_dhparam /path/to/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4";
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/chain.pem;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_buffer_size 4k;
```

The problem is that SSL connection time is quite high in my opinion (400ms), at least according to the [bytecheck.com](http://www.bytecheck.com). I heard that overly secure and slow ciphers can cause that, but I'm not sure if it's the case for me.

The website url is: [proseosite.ru](https://proseosite.ru)

Comment: *" I heard that overly secure and slow ciphers can cause that, but I'm not sure if it's the case for me."* - very unlikely with the ciphers you use. More likely is a high latency of the site in general, slowness due to long certificate chain and/or large certificates (4096 bit RSA instead of 2048 bit RSA or much smaller ECC)  and the client trying an OCSP lookup since no OCSP stapling is used. But these are just guesses - a better answer might be given if the domain in question is known.

Comment: There are other reasons to cut your cipher list down: Some of those, like RC4, are weak and should not be offered at all, not even for compatibility with antique operating systems. See https://cipherli.st/ for current recommendations.

Comment: I added the site url. Also, OCSP stapling is used (at least according to the digicert.com)